# Managing square brackets in dictionary keys with dpath library

Tags: python, dictionary, dpath

Using the `dpath` library, I'm having trouble working with a dictionary with keys containing square brackets. From the docs I see that square brackets are considered as elements of regular exporessions. However, this is causing the issue in my case, because I just want them to be "normal" square brackets.

I tried to escape the square brackets with a backspace `\[`, but the result is the same.

##### Code example

```py
import dpath

d = {'Position': {'Position x [mm]': 3}}
dpath.search(d, 'Position/Position x [mm]/*')
```

This outputs: `{}` instead of the expected  `{'Position': {'Position x [mm]': 3}}`

Maybe there is already a solution for the problem, but I did not find it in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like [`dpath` uses *`fnmatch`* library under the hood](https://github.com/dpath-maintainers/dpath-python/blob/master/dpath/segments.py#L2)(`fnmatch` module provides support for Unix shell-style wildcards, which are not the same as *regular expressions*). As [per the `fnmatch` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html),

> For a literal match, wrap the meta-characters in brackets. For
> example, '`[?]`' matches the character '`?`'

So you have to replace the `[` with `[[]` and `]` with `[]]` to get the expected match result.

```
>>> import dpath
>>> 
>>> d = {'Position': {'Position x [mm]': 3}}
>>> dpath.search(d, 'Position/Position x [[]mm[]]')
{'Position': {'Position x [mm]': 3}}
```